# How to send CTRL + v to terminal via terminal.sendSequence?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried reading the documentation on how to correctly figure this out, and I just got even more confused.

[The docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/advanced#_custom-sequence-keybindings) state commands only work with the `\u0000` format and links to this page [XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) make no mention of this `\u0000` format.

found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61742559/need-vscode-sendsequence-keybindings-for-previous-command-next-command-move-to) stack link, it helped abit but I still dont understand how I can get the code for `CTRL` + `v` that I can

use for `terminal.sendSequence`

Any help would be really wellcome

If you need context for why I need  `CTRL` + `v` for terminal via `terminal.sendSequence`, then read the following.

---

Currently in VScode, Clipboard pasting to the terminal is handeled by VScode, not Powershells PSReadline.

Why does this matter? If there are multiple lines in the clipboard VScode will paste and execute one line at a time, so the following:

```
Function Hello{
    Write-Host "Hello World"
}
```

When paste into a Powershell terminal:
Line 1:

```
Function Hello{
```

Line 2:

```
Write-Host "Hello World"
```

Line 3:

```
}
```

I have read and read to try and turn this of.
This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345026/wt-paste-multiple-lines-to-windows-terminal-without-executing) mentions that host procces is messing up the clipboard, therefore get PSReadline to handle pasting

I was able to confirm that this is the case with VScode and used this setting:

```
  "terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell": true,

  " `": [
    "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
  ],
```

Which fixed the issue, PSReadline handless pasting, but now PSReadline also handless every other keybinding, including the keys for the handy VSCode Find bar for Terminal.

I really dont want to go down the route of listing every command I want Vscode to handle under `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell`

Comment: Are you aware that `Ctrl` + `v` is a keyboard sequence, and that the `Ctrl` key is just like the `Shift` and `Alt` in that it modifies the scan code generated by the keyboard? A `Ctrl` + `v` keystroke is mapped to the ASCII code SYN or Synchronous Idle, which has the value 0x16 or 22 decimal. So a byte (or character) with value 0x16 is the same as a mapped `Ctrl` + `v` keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61742559/need-vscode-sendsequence-keybindings-for-previous-command-next-command-move-to) you provided references an [Xterm.js](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/0e45909c7e79c83452493d2cd46d99c0a0bb585f/src/common/data/EscapeSequences.ts) file that contains various control codes.

One of them listed is for `^V`:

```
  /** Synchronous Idle (Caret = ^V) */
  export const SYN = '\x16';
```

Use the characters after `\x` and replace them with the last 2 characters in the `\u00NN` code

For example, to trigger `Ctrl+v` in the terminal using `Ctrl+k Ctrl+enter` shortcut:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+enter",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { 
    "text": "\u0016"
  }
},
```

---

I had a similar issue when trying to send multi-line content to interactive node shell, and had to wrap the selected text between `.editor` and `Ctrl+D` as follows:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+enter",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && terminalIsOpen",
  "args": { 
    "text": ".editor\n${selectedText}\n\u0004"
  }
},
```

Note that `\u0004` corresponds to `Ctrl+D` in the above example.